# связанные подзапросы

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Объясните, пожалуйста, можно ли решить задачу используя только связные запросы (не используя JOIN)? и в чем здесь проблема?
>   Осуществить следующую выборку: - Список номеров рейсов для самолетов с максимальной дальностью полета

Сделал через соединения двумя способами в первом не выводил модель самолета, тк для поиска рейсов это не обязательно,
а в условии задачи прямо это не сказано.
Но в обоих случаях без JOIN не обойтись.

```
--связный запрос + JOIN
SELECT  Longitude, 
 (SELECT FlightId FROM Flights f WHERE f.ArrivalAirport = a.AirportName) 
 FROM Airports a WHERE Longitude=(SELECT MIN(Longitude) FROM Airports )


SELECT  FlightId, Longitude,
(SELECT AircraftCode FROM Aircrafts ac WHERE f.AircraftCode = ac.AircraftCode) Fligh
FROM Flights f JOIN Airports a ON f.ArrivalAirport = a.AirportName WHERE a.Longitude = (SELECT MIN(Longitude) FROM Airports)
```

> При попытке cделать двухуровневым связным запросом ошибка(оба варианта неверны) на последней строке:
>   "В списке выбора можно указать только одно выражение, если вложенный запрос не предварен EXISTS"

```
-- 2-х уровневый связный запрос (без JOIN)
--ac->f->a
            SELECT AircraftCode,
        (SELECT FlightId,
(SELECT Longitude FROM Airports a WHERE f.ActualArrival = a.AirportName AND Longitude =(SELECT MIN(Longitude) FROM Airports))
        FROM Flights f WHERE f.AircraftCode = ac.AircraftCode)
            FROM AirCrafts ac 

--a->f->ac
            SELECT Longitude,
        (SELECT FlightId,
(SELECT AircraftCode FROM AirCrafts ac WHERE f.AircraftCode = ac.AircraftCode AND f.ActualArrival = a.AirportName)
        FROM Flights f WHERE f.ActualArrival = a.AirportName)
            FROM Airports a WHERE Longitude =(SELECT MIN(Longitude) FROM Airports)
```

[image: на картинке схема]

Answer (score 0):

ответ прост

при вложенной выборке

```
 SELSECT c
  (SELECT a from b) 
 from c
```

`SELECT a from b` должен гарантированно возвращать одну запись, иначе будет ошибка

добавьте top 1 b работать будет но верно или нет разбирать вам

```
(SELECT top 1 a from b)
```